# Flask Function Running But Not Commiting to Database

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, commit

I had this code working where I was able to post, and ending up playing with sessions a bit and adding a comment section. Now although the fields are displaying correctly, minus any css so far, I cannot post, and have no idea why. The python is identical to how it was before messing around with sessions, but it will not commit any information to the database, but will still run the function, as it reloads the page. It does not seem to be throwing any errors either, what changed that isn't allowing me to post now? URL of page in question: https://the49oproject.herokuapp.com/frontpage

Site Python Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re
import psycopg2
import os
import random
from datetime import datetime


DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/frontpage", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def frontpage():
    #get session, and get username from session - from there load in post data based off user into frontpage

    if request.method=='POST' and 'post' in request.form:
        today = datetime.now()
        postdesc = request.form['post']
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO post (post_desc, created) VALUES (%s,%s)', (postdesc,today,))
        conn.commit()
        return redirect('/frontpage')


    if request.method=='POST' and 'comment' in request.form:
        commtoday = datetime.now()
        comment = request.form['comment']
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO comment (comment, created) VALUES (%s,%s)', (comment,commtoday,))
        conn.commit()
        return redirect('/frontpage')
    """
    if 'username' in session:
        username=session['username']
        cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username=%s', (username,))
        id = cur.fetchone()
    """

    cur.execute('SELECT login.user_id, post.user_id_fk, login.username, post.post, post.post_desc, post.created, post.post_id FROM login, post WHERE login.user_id = post.user_id_fk')
    simposts = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('SELECT post.post_id, comment.post_id_fk, comment.comment, comment.created FROM post, comment WHERE post.post_id = comment.post_id_fk')
    comments=cur.fetchall()
    return render_template("frontpage.html", simposts=simposts, comments=comments)
```

Front Page HTML

```
        <main>
            <div class="home-center">
                <div class="top-bar">
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="post-box">
                    <div class="input-section">
                        <form id="post"  method=post action="{{url_for('frontpage')}}">
                            <input type="text" name="post" placeholder="What's Cooking?">
                            <a href="{{ url_for('frontpage')}}">
                            <button type="button" name="send-post">Post</button>
                            </a>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="post-timeline">
                    <table class="table">
                        {% for i in simposts %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{i[2]}}</td>
                            <td>{{i[3]}}</td>
                            <td>{{i[4]}}</td>
                            <td>{{i[5]}}</td>

                        </tr>

                        <form id="comment" method=post action="{{url_for('frontpage')}}">
                            <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Comment Here">
                            <a href="{{ url_for('frontpage')}}">
                            <button type="button" name="post-comment">comment</button>
                            </a>
                        </form>
                        <table class="table">
                            {% for com in comments %}
                            <tr>
                                {% if i[6]==com[1] %}
                                    <td>{{com[2]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{com[3]}}</td>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div></div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>

                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Have you hosted app on heroku then you can't use sqlite file for storing database. See [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted&ved=2ahUKEwj75q7C0ozxAhVTwTgGHd_-AQUQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw3NjxAanHnKWMeK61UBgGcV) , use postgresql addons of heroku.

Comment: Also you have to use flask-sqlalchemy if you do with postgresql and I see that there are no quotation Mark's around post in font page html.

Comment: I am using heroku, postgresql, and have saved data fine before without sqlalchemy.

Comment: ok that's good but have you added quotation mark, is it working now